# GemFire delta propagation thread-safety

Tags: gemfire

GemFire allows to reduce network load during updates by sending deltas instead of fully blown object by implementing the [`Delta`](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/javadocs/japi/com/gemstone/gemfire/Delta.html) interface (`hasDelta`, `toDelta` and `fromDelta`).

Can one assume that if multiple updates are received for the same key from different updaters the above methods are not run concurrently on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GemFire (now Apache Geode(Incubating)) pre-calculates the "delta" bits of an incoming `Delta` update. So `hasDelta` and `toDelta` are invoked on the new value, even before it is "actually" put into the `Region`, and are **not** synchronized. The application/implementation needs to take care of it. Also, note that `toDelta` is only invoked at the first member where the update originates.

On the other hand, `fromDelta` gets invoked on the existing value (at receiving member's cache) after taking a lock on the key's entry, at the time of "actually" putting the new value into the `Region`. Delta-updates on different keys happen concurrently, just like normal updates.

`Region` attribute `cloning-enabled` or `Cache` attribute `copy-on-read` decide whether the delta-bits get applied to the existing value in-place or to its copy.

How/where the delta-events are distributed is pretty similar to how normal event-distribution happens in GemFire.

If you have not already done so, visit [this page](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/gemfire_nativeclient/delta-propagation/delta-propagation.html) this page for more details.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please elaborate on the "synchronized environment" part? Are all changes delegated from other machines being applied sequentially, or only the changes on the same key? Is it mentioned in docs somewhere?

Comment: Apologies, if the answer wasn't clear earlier. I have updated it with more details.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The answer was clear enough earlier and it's even better now; all I wanted is a confirmation in the official documentation as I couldn't find any (and still can't).